# DispatcherTimer stops when Windows Phone 8 app is in background mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a dispatcher timer running, and when I send the app to the background the timer stops "ticking" (and continues to run when the app is reactivated).

I need the timer to continue ticking when the app is in background mode. The timer is updating a TextBlock.

How I can achieve this? By the way I'm already using:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean running under lock screen, if you disable ApplicationIdleDetectionMode, your `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` will work as well as any other Timer.
If you don't disable idle it will stop as it is said at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):
`This event (Deactivation) is also raised if the device’s lock screen is engaged, unless application idle detection is disabled.`
If you want to run in the background (eg. after pressing Start buton), you won't be able to do this with any timer as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) says:
`When the user navigates forward, away from an app, after the Deactivated event is raised, the operating system will attempt to put the app into a dormant state. In this state, all of the application’s threads are stopped and no processing takes place, but the application remains intact in memory.`
The bigger problem is when your App is tombstoned - the app doesn't ramain (all) in memory.
You can try with [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but that is other story and they probably won't be suitable to update TextBlock.
**EDIT**
And why not to remember the time when the user deactivates the App in `PhoneApplicationService.Current.State` or `IsolatedStorageSettings`, and when the user activates again, calculate the difference and do what you want, depending on that value?

Answer (score 2):

`DispatcherTimer` runs on the UI thread, so it makes sense that it gets stopped when the application is running in the background, you can try with a different timer instead, like [Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I think that won't work as with Deactivation Event all application's threads are stopped.